# Scrapy not passing correct item through meta attribute

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm having a similar problem that the individual below had. I'm trying to pass an item using the meta attribute. I'm seeing the correct number of items outputted, but they are duplicates of a single item. Could someone help? I'm guessing mby the response to the previous individual's post that this should be an obvious fix.

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1257

```
def parse(self, response):
# some treatment
# a loop
     request = scrapy.Request(url=<calculated_url>, callback=parseChapter)
     request.meta['item'] = # a dictionary containing some data of the just parsed page
     yield request

def parseChapter(self, response):
# some treatment
# a loop
     request = scrapy.Request(url=<calculated_url>, callback=parseCategory)
     request.meta['item'] = # a dictionary containing some data of the just parsed page
     # print request.meta['item'] is good and different in every iteration
     yield request

def parseCategory(self, response):
# print response.meta['item'] is not good because it displays the same value many times
# for every new call of parseChapter, meta['item'] received is always the same
# some treatment
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your complete code and the error message. Otherwise it's a pure matter of guessing what causes your problem.

Comment: the correct answer is change request.meta['item'] = item to request.meta['item'] = item.copy() (unless someone more knowledgeable disagrees)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you modifying the item at each iteration of the for loop instead of creating a new one.

As a consequence all request are being sent with the same value. i.e. the last value of the item variable.

```
def parseChapter(self, response):
# some treatment
# a loop
     request = scrapy.Request(url=<calculated_url>, callback=parseCategory)
     request.meta['item'] = my_item_dict.copy()
     # print request.meta['item'] is good and different in every iteration
     yield request
```

Comment: this should work:

`for loop: 
    item = PlaceItem() ... other code...`

Comment: would help to describe exact solution if you published full code of parseChapter